# How to improve webpack performance?

Tags: javascript, gulp, reactjs, browserify, webpack

I recently switched from browserify to webpack and the build time jumped from 4s to 16s on (2014 MBP).  I understand webpack does alot more than browserify but i shouldn't take that long. My build process is fairly simple. Are there any tips or options to improve my build time?

```
var webpackOptions = {
  cache : true,
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
    ]
  },
};


gulp.task('buildJs', function(){ 
    multipipe(
      gulp.src(jsSrcPath),
      named(),
      webpack(webpackOptions),
      uglify(),
      gulp.dest(jsDestPath)
    ).on('error', function(error){
      console.log(error)
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using webpack via gulp and webpack? Just curious :)

Answer (score 24):

You should set `include` paths for your loaders. Example:

```
{ test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader', include: jsSrcPath }
```

Consider doing the same for that css case.

In my experience this can give massive gains as it doesn't have to traverse through `node_modules` anymore. Alternatively you could `exclude` `node_modules` but I find it neater just to set up that `include`. It gets more complicated if you are requiring content out of the include path, though.

[Docs for include/exclude](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders)

Comment: browserify is not applying transforms to `node_modules`, that's the reason why it's faster (out of the box)

Comment: @timaschew Yeah, that explains it effectively. With webpack `include` is a very good idea.

Comment: Thank you made a huge difference for me.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `noParse` option for big files, like jquery and angular.

Examples here: https://github.com/jeffling/angular-webpack-example/blob/b2b59dff60c35ee6d70170948ab15bba8af5e613/template/webpack.config.coffee#L60

Also, if you set `cache` to true, when watching it rebuilds a *lot faster*.

Another technique to increasing speed is to put big dependencies that you aren't going to edit into a separate bundle.

Comment: I like the idea of putting big dependencies in a seperate bundle (for example jquery, or angular). However, how would one require('jquery') and use it in the main app bundle?

Comment: Just make sure both bundles are included in your html and it should work

Comment: Caching is set to true by default for watching.

Answer (score 1):

Recently a new module loader, [HappyPack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/happypack) (not written by me), makes heavy use of parallelization and disk caching to improve build times on large code bases pretty significantly. Compile times on my code base went from 40 seconds to 10. It's still a pretty new library though, so it's not extremely well documented or user friendly. Worth taking a look at though.

Comment: In my case happyloader unfortunatelly didn't help, hovewer   devtool: 'eval-source-map', helped a little bit.